# How do I convert my list of codons into the corresponding amino acids from my dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I think this is very simple, but I need some help.  I have a list of codons like this:

```
codons=['CTC','AGG','TTT']
```

And I have a dictionary that matches up the codons to their corresponding amino acids.  How do I then take what I have in this list and change the codons into amino acids?

For example, my coding is as follows:

```
aa_codons=['CTT':'Leu','CCT':'Pro','CGA':'Arg'] 
nt_seq=['CTT','CTT','CGA','CCT','CGA']
```

Then I was trying to do something like

```
for x in nt_seq:     
    print aa_codons[key]
```

Comment: Is `[aa_dict[codon] for codon in codons]` what you're looking for?

Comment: On a broader note, if you're going to be doing much of this kind of work, check out [Biopython](http://www.biopython.org). It has all sorts of (among other things) built in translation tables for codons, amino acids, and sequences, using a variety of alphabets, like IUPACProtein or mRNA or mtDNA. The [tutorial](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html) will show you everything...

Comment: If you'd like to help us help you, you might want to post the `dictionary that matches up the codons to their corresponding amino acids` (or some representative subset of it). Also, have you tried something that doesn't work? Why don't you post your past attempts so that we can explain to what didn't work, rather than simply give you code that you may or may not fully understand

Comment: Well, normally I would be doing that.  Right now I am just trying to say that I have these elements in my list, and according to the dictionary I made, these elements stand for a specific amino acid that my dictionary says they stand for.

Comment: aa_codons=['CTT',:'Leu','CCT':'Pro','CGA':'Arg']
nt_seq=['CTT','CTT','CGA','CCT','CGA']

then I was trying to do something like
for x in nt_seq:
    and then I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Did `[aa_codons[codon] for codon in nt_seq]` work?

Comment: First, your `aa_codons` is syntactically incorrect. Second, please edit it into your post, rather than adding it as a comment, as it clarifies your post for everyone, not just those reading the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavidRobinson suggested:

```
In [22]: nt_seq=['CTT','CTT','CGA','CCT','CGA'] 

In [23]: [aa_codons[codon] for codon in nt_seq]
Out[23]: ['Leu', 'Leu', 'Arg', 'Pro', 'Arg']

In [24]: nt_seq=['CTT','CTT','CGA','CCT','CGA']

In [25]: aa_codons={'CTT':'Leu','CCT':'Pro','CGA':'Arg'}

In [26]: [aa_codons[codon] for codon in nt_seq]
Out[26]: ['Leu', 'Leu', 'Arg', 'Pro', 'Arg']
```